# properties file not found when running testNG as executable jar file

Tags: java, junit, jar, testng, pom.xml

I wrote a Java Class to run a JUnit Test and it looks like:

```java
public class test_runner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestNG test = new TestNG();
      TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
      test.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Test.class });
      test.addListener(tla);
      test.run();
   }
}
```

When I run this within the workspace, everything's fine and the tests in my `Test.class` will run. But when I export `test_runner.class` as an executable jar file and run it with `java -jar test_runner.jar running` the testcase fails, because the path to the properties file is null. Can somebody tell me what the problem is? 
My `pom.xml` looks like the following. Maybe a plugin is missing?

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fja.cor.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaguar-test-verka</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <properties>
        <resultoutputdirectory>X:/Testmanagement/Jaguar/jaguar-logs/${maven.build.timestamp}</resultoutputdirectory>
        <testSuite>src/test/resources/testsuites/VerkaSuite1.xml</testSuite>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <!--<url>${url}</url>
                        <errPath>${errPath}</errPath>
                        <webdriver.firefox.bin>C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox</webdriver.firefox.bin>
                        <webdriver.ie.driver>D:/jaguar/IEDriverServer.exe</webdriver.ie.driver>
                        <FAGT_VTRNR>${FAGT_VTRNR}</FAGT_VTRNR>-->
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${testSuite}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>com.cor.fja.jaguar.architecture.listener.JaguarErrListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>2.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-testng-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0b1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-swing</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-swing-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fja.cor.jaguar</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaguar-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <outputDirectory>${resultoutputdirectory}/TestResult-${maven.build.timestamp}</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputName>TestResult</outputName>
                    <outputDirectory>${resultoutputdirectory}/TestResult-${maven.build.timestamp}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${resultoutputdirectory}/TestResult-${maven.build.timestamp}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Where exactly is a property file being used in the code that you shared? Can you please tell us how does your `Test.java` look like ? Also please share the complete exception stacktrace.

Comment: The property file is being used when i initialize a testcase in the setUp method i have overwritten.

Comment: It is a little too complicated to tell you how my Test.java look like, because it is a huge project, which is about testing a intrawebsurface. I dont think the problem is in the testcase, because i get the same problem when i just wanted to print "hello world" or something like that. 
the exception got caught in one of the functions in the setUp method and just said that one path, which should be set by the property file is null. I hope this helps.

Comment: No it doesn't help. Without additional context it's hard to suggest where could be the problem.